# How do I enable auto-increment feature [please read details]

Tags: c#, oracle, primary-key, auto-increment

```
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("applicationid", flag);

xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstname", fname.Text);

xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("middlename", mname.Text);
```

These values are to be stored to a oracle 11g databse. How can I enable the auto-increment feature for `applicationid` field. I know I can use sequences, but how do I collectively implement that with c# and oracle?

Comment: Just make that feild `Identity` and it will autoincrement itself.

Comment: Define it in DB and don't insert value from C#.

Comment: See [**Auto-increment primary key in Pre 12c releases**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/20/auto-increment-primary-key-in-pre-12c-releases-identity-functionality/) and [**IDENTITY column autoincrement functionality in Oracle 12c**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/20/identity-column-autoincrement-functionality-in-oracle-12c/)

Comment: I don't seem to understand why this question has been marked duplicate @Lalit Kumar B , because I want to know what changes I want to make in my visual c# code. The link that you've provided only answers the database end of it

Comment: @akshaydhingra You just need to make changes in database and nothing in your application code. Your requirement is to auto-increment the column when rows are inserted. How is it related to `C#`? Or do you want it to be handled by `C#` code?

Comment: Yes. I want the insertion to be executed through a visual c# form. @LalitKumarB

Comment: @akshaydhingra You are still not getting the point. Just insert other values, and no need to insert the `applicationid` at all from your `C#` code. It will be auto-incremented in the database automatically. That is what the topic marked as duplicate shows.

Comment: @MairajAhmad it depens on OP's database version. Identity columns are introduced in 12c.

Comment: I get your point. That does not work for oracle 11g. It does work for other databases. @LalitKumarB

Comment: @akshaydhingra There are two solutions given for `12c` and `pre-12c` i.e. `11g` and before. So how do you say it does not work for 11g?

Comment: I tried. My supervisor is saying you have to create a sequence and use something like seq.nextval and the fact that an empty value cannot be given in the c# code. so instead of flag what should i write? @LalitKumarB

Comment: @akshaydhingra Tell your supervisor that you need not require that column in the `C#` code at all. The fact that the trigger will automatically insert the sequence.nextval in the database column.